# Issue when running expect script in ssh session

Tags: ssh, expect

On server2 I have expect script java_kill which kills some process by powershell on server3.
It works fine when I run this from server2, but when I run this from server1 I can't see process is killed. Why is that?

From server1 I run such command:

```
ssh user@server2 './java_kill'
```

java_kill expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh -l user@adr server3
expect "*passphrase*"
send "passphrase\r"
expect "*assword*"
send "password\r"
expect "*>"
send "powershell.exe\r"
expect "PS*> "
send "Get-Process Java | Stop-Process\r"
expect "*"
send "exit\r"
```

Server1 expect logs:

```
# not relevant lines are unmentioned
send: sending "powershell.exe\r" to { exp5 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "PS*> "? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "Get-Process Java | Stop-Process\r" to { exp5 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "*"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) ""
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp5"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""
send: sending "exit\r" to { exp5 }
```

Comment: My initial reaction is `ssh -t user@server2 './java_kill'`

Comment: replace `expect "*"` with `expect "PS*> "`

Comment: @glennjackman indeed you are right, it works, what `ssh -t` does?

Comment: @pynexj good clue, after replacing `expect "*"` with `expect "PS*> "` I see output of `send "Get-Process Java | Stop-Process\r"`. Why I couldn't see when `expect "*"` was in place? Asterisk "*" should cover all strings also "PS*> ", right?

Comment: from `man expect`: The pattern `"*"` (and `-re ".*"`) will flush the output buffer **without reading any more** output from the process.

Comment: see `man ssh` for `ssh -t`.

Comment: Ok, why not to use `ssh -t` in the script as well? I think it would be better, am I right?